# The difference between UINavigationBar and UIToolbar rendering process

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

This is a basic question, but I realized that both of these bars have different rendering process. Why is that?

If I use an image specifically designed for UIToolbar items, and try to use it on UINavigationBar items, it doesn't render in the same way. It seems to be not rendered at all in the UINavigationBar.

So, I have to create a different image for both of these types of bar.
Is this a bug or an intended design? Am I missing something here? Is there any special setup to make both bars render their items in the same way?

Comment: a background image should render the same way in different `UIView`. Are you on iOS7 or below? Can you post a screenshot?